# Xcode fails to compile for real iPad but works for simulator (missing header files in netinet)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Xcode version 6.2 building for iOS 8.2.  I have an application that builds and runs in the iphone and ipad simulator but when I try to build and deploy to a real i-device the compile fails.

The header files under netinet in these 2 directories are vastly different:

`

```
ls -al /Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/netinet
total 40
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel    204 Mar 19 11:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x  154 root  wheel   5236 Mar 19 11:01 ../
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  27431 Mar 10 11:29 in.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4001 Mar 10 11:29 in_systm.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8097 Mar 10 11:29 ip.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8946 Mar 10 11:29 tcp.h
```

`

```
ls -al /Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/netinet
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   24 root  wheel    816 Feb 10 00:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x  206 root  wheel   7004 Mar 10 11:31 ../
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4165 Mar 10 11:30 bootp.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  24679 Mar 10 11:30 icmp6.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4577 Mar 10 11:30 icmp_var.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5832 Mar 10 11:30 if_ether.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   7093 Mar 10 11:30 igmp.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5839 Mar 10 11:30 igmp_var.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  27431 Mar 10 11:30 in.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   9496 Mar 10 11:30 in_pcb.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4001 Mar 10 11:30 in_systm.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5574 Mar 10 11:30 in_var.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8097 Mar 10 11:30 ip.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  11034 Mar 10 11:30 ip6.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   9471 Mar 10 11:30 ip_icmp.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   6237 Mar 10 11:30 ip_var.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   8946 Mar 10 11:30 tcp.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5181 Mar 10 11:30 tcp_fsm.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4484 Mar 10 11:30 tcp_seq.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   6772 Mar 10 11:30 tcp_timer.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  22554 Mar 10 11:30 tcp_var.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   4271 Mar 10 11:30 tcpip.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   3694 Mar 10 11:30 udp.h
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   5659 Mar 10 11:30 udp_var.h
```

I can work around it by creating links that point to the simulator header files but that feels wrong.

Is there a reason for what I'm seeing?

Comment: Which specific headers are you having problems with?  Many of those headers are primarily intended for kernel usage and aren't usually needed for user space development.

Comment: One of the libraries I'm using needs something in udp.h

Comment: I had the same issue and copied the files I needed into a separate directory in my project. I then included them as "net/<file>.h" rather than <net/<file>.h>

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel, I started down that path but had to copy udp.h, then ip_var.h, ip_icmp.h, ...then it started to cascade on me and I got a bad feeling in my gut :)

Comment: Thanks for whoever down-voted it without a comment.  You win.

Comment: Down vote makes no sense. Bumped you back. It is a very real issue. Seems it has been around for while. This link has a handy script to do the necessary linkage. http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2010/02/13/using-apples-simpleping-on-iphone-os/

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel, I ended up creating soft links to a # of headers.  It's not clear to me why the simulator build would be any different.  My original question was based on my assumption that there was something I simply "didn't get".  I appreciate the help and have now successfully built my IPA.